# how can i get datacontractjsonserializer to work with a string?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, json

I have the following code which only works while using a filestream and reading a file, how can I make it work using a string in the format of a json?

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("c://test"))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(datastruct));
    datastruct struct= (datastruct )ser.ReadObject(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering "json" is your string:

```
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
                sw.Write(json);
                sw.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Item));
                var type = ser.ReadObject(ms);
```